# ECS DescribeTasksResponse always returns an empty `networkBindings`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I couldn't find a way to get the public IP the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ecs/classes/describetaskscommand.html) says it should be in the response:

```
 * const command = new DescribeTasksCommand(input);
 * const response = await client.send(command);
 * // { // DescribeTasksResponse
 * //   tasks: [ // Tasks
 * //     { // Task
 * //       attachments: [ // Attachments
 * //        ...
 * //       ],
 * //       ...
 * //       containers: [ // Containers
 * //         { // Container
 * //           containerArn: "STRING_VALUE",
 * //           taskArn: "STRING_VALUE",
 * //           name: "STRING_VALUE",
 * //           ...
 * //           networkBindings: [ // NetworkBindings
 * //             { // NetworkBinding
 * //               bindIP: "STRING_VALUE",
 * //               containerPort: Number("int"),
 * //               hostPort: Number("int"),
 * //               protocol: "tcp" || "udp",
 * //               containerPortRange: "STRING_VALUE",
 * //               hostPortRange: "STRING_VALUE",
 * //             },
 * //           ],
```

My code:

```js
  let waitECSTask = await waitUntilTasksRunning(
    {"client": ecsClient, "maxWaitTime": 6000, "maxDelay": 1, "minDelay": 1}, 
    {"cluster": "my_cluster", "tasks": [taskArn]}
  )
```

But I'm always getting an empty list in `waitECSTask` of `networkBindings` but looking at AWS console I do see that a public IP was allocated.

Comment: Are you actually setting `networkBindings` values in the task definition? The public IP is not part of the container networkBindings, it is a network NAT thing that happens at the task ENI level, not the container level.

Comment: I'm not setting it when starting the task, but I do want to get it after the task was created. I do get the private IP but not the public

Comment: Look at the example for `describe-tasks` here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html The Elastic Network Interface information is going to be under `attachments` not `cluster.networkBindings`

Comment: I scanned the all DescribeTasksResponse it doesn't hold the public IP anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was refereed to the link: https://medium.com/the-aws-coder/create-and-run-aws-ecs-task-programmatically-using-net-5-c-aws-ecs-sdk-82b31df98fd3
It's in c# but does provide a good start, so apparently there's no simple solution, the way to get the public IP is by the EC2 API.

This is how the code in TS looks like:

```js
    import { EC2Client, DescribeNetworkInterfacesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ec2";

    ...


    const command = new DescribeNetworkInterfacesCommand({
        Filters: [
            {
                Name: "private-ip-address",
                Values: [waitECSTask.reason?.tasks[0].containers[0].networkInterfaces[0].privateIpv4Address],
            },
        ],
    });

    // Get the public IP address of the ECS task
    let network = await ec2Client.send(command)
    let publicIp = network.NetworkInterfaces?.[0].Association?.PublicIp?.toString() ?? "";
```